# REGEX Match a String (Google Analytics)

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to pull out links only have just string with excluding numbers and queries in URL in Google Analytics.

so, I need this URL

```
  www.site.com/en/rent/cairo/apartments-for-rent/
```

and exclude these

```
www.site.com/en/buy/apartment-for-sale-in-acacia-compound-new-cairo-947145/

  www.site.com/en/buy/apartment-for-sale-in-acacia-compound-new-cairo-947145/?price=1000
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each URL is on its own line, and that's the only thing on the line (not even whitespace), this simple regex will do the trick: `^[^0-9|?| ]*$`